# All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

While tring to update
 `'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'` to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'`
I am getting this error

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 11.8.0, 10.2.0. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0

How can I solve this error?

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName '1.1'

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
//    configurations {
//        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
//    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
            }
        }

    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':platform')
    compile project(':ahbottomnavigation')
    compile project(':mylibrary')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    }
    compile project(':bottom-bar')
    compile project(':journey')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.9.0'
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion=='27.1.0'**

Comment: Provide your app build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how your *build.gradle* for sub-projects look like, they should have same version as your *app build.gradle*, if you used any of `com.google.` libs inside the sub-projects.

However your `compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0')` should have the same version `11.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following dependency to `11.8.0`:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'mediarouter-v7'
}
```

because firebase-crash using `11.8.0`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

All the google gms dependencies and firebase dependencies must have the same version number. For eg. in your case, you are using `11.8.0` for Firebase but `10.2.0` for `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the versions of google play services and firebase you are referring to are quite old. Now, see the following:

Google Play Service - [latest set of libraries](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Firebase - [latest set of libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Secondly, once you upgrade, you might find that you can't get the same version of all the libraries, and that is by design. Google now uses a new versioning system, as written in their May 2018 blog post [announcing new SDK versioning](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html). So it is no longer appropriate to use all the same version number. According to google, upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 to stop getting that warning.